# Failure to reconnect to networks on iOS

Tags: ios, network, wifi, airport

Since installing iOS 14.0 (now 14.2) my iPhone XS repeatedly fails to reconnect to my network after returning from being out of range (e.g., on a walk) and frequently loses the network connection after periods of inactivity (e.g. overnight). No other device on my network has this problem. In order to reconnect I need to do so manually from scratch each time.

What can I do to ensure that my iPhone reconnects? I've tried deleting the offending network connection, resetting network connections, rebooting (and power cutting), rebooting the router — but nothing has helped? Is this a known bug introduced in iOS 14? If so is a fix forthcoming?

---

The network in question is hidden and MAC filtered, running on an AirPort Extreme. The connection is always configured to disable private addressing and to auto join.

Comment: Same issue.  I would love to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

***Things to try...*** is the same behavior observed if you:

- borrow an iDevice *(running iOS 14)* from someone else and connect it to your network
- temporarily disable MAC filtering and/or the hidden attribute of your wireless network

*(I’ve made the assumption that you’ve already re-booted both your iOS device and the Airport Extreme, and that they both have the most current software.)*

As a last resort (that won’t cause you to lose any data, but that will delete any saved WiFi passwords not saved to iCloud - maybe turn off iCloud first just to be safe):

- Use the “Reset Network Settings” option under Settings > General > Reset

---

***While not the issue in your case***, others may encounter a similar issue with the ‘private address’ feature in iOS 14, on a network has MAC filtering enabled.

1. When connected to your network, does “Privacy Warning” appear under the network name on the Wi-Fi settings?
2. If not, click the info circle to the right of the network name, then toggle off the “Private Address” option, which by default in iOS 14 assigns a new MAC address to your device on a regular basis *(each time? every day?)*